# Understanding the meaning of the notation $\binom{n+m}{n,m}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

From the wikepedia,

> For self-avoiding walks from one end of a diagonal to the other, with
>   only moves in the positive direction, there are exactly
>   $$ 
> \binom{n+m}{n,m}
> $$paths for an $m × n$ rectangular lattice.

Can I write $\binom{n+m}{n,m}$ = $\frac{(n+m)!}{n! \times m!}$? If not, how to evaluate $\binom{n+m}{n,m}$?

Comment: Well what is the meaning of the notation? I think the comma means choose n and then choose m.

Comment: I think this is the Multinomial Coefficient. If so, then your evaluation is correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

This is just the binomial coefficient and is usually written as:
$$\binom {n+m}n=\binom {n+m}m=\frac {(n+m)!}{n!m!}$$

---

NB: an example of a multinomial coefficient would be 
$$\binom {n+m+p+q}{n,m,p,q}=\frac {(n+m+p+q)!}{n!m!p!q!}$$